# Python numexpr module not found

Tags: python

I installed in the past numexpr successfully on many machine. But now I just cannot manage
to get it run on a new Linux system. Essentially I download the tar.gz file and

```
python setup.py install --home=~/Python/
```

which nicely works. I also did

```
export PYTHONPATH+=:$HOME/Python/lib/python/
```

This procedure works nicely for a couple of other modules on the machine, but for numexpr
I keep getting

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Jul 22 2011, 11:30:26) 
[GCC 4.4.4 20100726 (Bull 4.4.4-13)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numexpr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numexpr
```

I tried version 1.4.1 and 1.4.2 of numexpr. Also the sys.path is correctly set in the python environment (as it should be).

Does anybody have an idea what could go wrong here?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: are you on a 64 bit system?  do you have both lib and lib64 in $HOME/Python?  if so, what are their contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$HOME/Python/lib/python/` is probably not a correct value for the PYTHONPATH, the modules are usually installed in subdirectory below the installation dir, usually with a version number after `python` etc. I think this problem is solvable by just looking at what is under `~/Python`

Comment: Then, look under ~/Python and find where the "numexpr" subdirectory is, and adjust your PYTHONPATH accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Anaconda free distribution [link](http://continuum.io/downloads). Your coding life with python will be much more easier. Also, numexpr is already installed and ready to be used (with other packages too).